# Orientation of linestring with North arrow pointing up

Tags: qgis, postgis, azimuth

With PostGIS I am trying to calculate the azimuth of a linestring in order to use it then in a print composer in QGIS, using an atlas. But since the azimuth is calculated by comparing startpoint and endpoint of the linestring, and the startpoint can be further North OR further South than the endpoint, I do not necessarily get a value resulting with the North arrow pointing in the upper 180° of my map. 
I would like it to do so, and so my North arrow would never point in any southern direction. I am guessing there is a formula to make absolute the azimuth and so giving me what I need, but I didn't manage to figure that out. 
Would anyone have a way to do so, whether it is in QGIS or directly through PostGIS?

Answer (score 1):

The [azimuth](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Azimuth.html) is always positive, with a value of 0 to the North and 3 Pi/2 to the West. To always point toward the "top", you must filter values between Pi/2 and 3 Pi/2, and subtract Pi

```
WITH src(geom) AS 
  (values ('LINESTRING(0 0, 0 1)'),
          ('LINESTRING(0 1, 0 0)'),
          ('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1)'),
          ('LINESTRING(1 1, 0 0)')
  ),
  azim AS (
     SELECT ST_Azimuth(st_startPoint(geom),st_EndPoint(geom)) as az
  FROM src)
SELECT az, 
 CASE WHEN az <= pi()/2 OR az >= 3*pi()/2 THEN az 
      ELSE az - pi() END AS north_az
 FROM azim;

         az         |      north_az
--------------------+--------------------
                  0 |                  0
  3.141592653589793 |                  0
 0.7853981633974483 | 0.7853981633974483
 3.9269908169872423 | 0.7853981633974492
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand one thing: there is an orientation for the second line with the azimuth, and it turns to 0. I would like to get the result for this case too.